# How to add repeat-x for table td with background url

Tags: html, css

I have html table where three tds are there, i need to add an image for the middle td in a tr with the property repeat-x; property. But its not working for me.
    My code:

```
     <td style="background-image:url('repeatbanner.png');background-repeat: repeat-x;">
```

I have tried width:auto also, but no result.Please try to help me.

Comment: show your code and preferably make a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: hope your path is correct.

Comment: @Era my path is correct and i am getting image, but not repeatedly.

Comment: @RajasekharP : in which browser you are getting this issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rcGv4/ its working here perfect.

Comment: You really need provide testable case. Perhaps the cell just isn’t wide enough to cause the background image to be repeated.

Comment: I created a fiddle and this works fine. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/5xxHT/2/ Are you sure that your path is totally correct? Maybe try to add the whole url to the image and look if it's working? :)

Comment: Roman and @Era if we remove the text(dgfdg) between start and end tags..its not repeating, plz try that..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rcGv4/1/ its working for me.. we just need to increase width.

Comment: @Era its working fine with your previous answer, please make it as answer i will mark it as answer thankyou soooooo much..for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcGv4)

```
<table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url(https://www.google.co.in/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; ">dgfdg</td>
        <td>gdgd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```